# How to enable the option to select a profile

Tags: firefox

I selected 'Don't ask Profile selection option during startup', but how do I disable it since it doesn't allow me to choose a profile prior to startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from command line: `firefox -ProfileManager` will ask for profile

see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, sounds like you want to unselect "Don't ask Profile", then it will ask you. And like RC said, running firefox -P, when firefox is not already running, will allow you to check or uncheck that box in the ProfileManager dialog.

Assuming you're running my version 3.6.16., but I'm pretty sure that's been around for a while.

Comment: On Mozilla Firefox 11.0      ,

`-P profile`  
Start  firefox with the profile named profile. Will start the profile manager if a valid profile name is not specified. You will need to also use -no-remote if there is already a running firefox instance.

Answer (score 0):

Some times

```
firefox -profilemanager
```

may not work, if it is so, try

```
firefox --profilemanager
```

[image]

It will open the profile manager window, You could click on "create new" button, give it a relevant name, also specify a location where you want the profile informations to be stored. Then click finish.

Open it again
Uncheck the "Don't ask at start up" checkbox. Then click ok. I think you are done.